# Drop list down (item after item) on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, click

I have a line of text with a list below it. I would like to click the text and the list drops down – specifically, one item after the other in quick-ish succession to give a nice smooth effect. I hope this is clear. What is the best way to achieve this? Code below. Thanks.

Note: Almost no javascript/jquery knowledge as of yet. Apologies.

HTML:

```
<p class="facilities" style="color:#009ee3" id="perth-features">Key features</p>        
  <ul class="facilities" id="perth-list">
    <li>15,000m² heavy duty concrete hardstand open storage</li>
    <li>1,900m² heavy duty concrete undercover canopy area</li>
    <li>5,550m² high truss warehouse space</li>
    <li>1,600m² maintenance facility</li>
    <li>45,000 Litre self bunded diesel fuelling station</li>
    <li>700m² Spare parts area for fleet &amp; rental spares</li>
    <li>460m² segregated undercover</li>
    <li>90m² truck wash bay facility with oil separation system</li>
    <li>Onsite lifting to 16tonne</li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

CSS

```
#perth-list {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055914/jquery-smoothscroll-and-select-option) answer

Comment: @LowMatic This doesn't seem to be what I am looking for. Sorry if it's not clear. I want it so that when "key features" is clicked, the unordered list appears. I just want it to appear by each list item sliding down (or in from left) individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery you can do something along these lines:

```js
var speed = 100

$("#perth-features").click(function() {
  var canAnimate = true;
  $("ul#perth-list li").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).is(":animated"))
      return canAnimate = false;
  });

  if (canAnimate)
    $("ul#perth-list li").each(function(index) {
      if (!$(this).is(":visible"))
        $(this).delay(speed * index).slideDown(speed);
      else
        $(this).delay(speed * ($("ul#perth-list li").length - index)).slideUp(speed);
    });
});
```

```css
ul#perth-list li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="facilities" style="color:#009ee3" id="perth-features">Key features</p>
<ul class="facilities" id="perth-list">
  <li>15,000m² heavy duty concrete hardstand open storage</li>
  <li>1,900m² heavy duty concrete undercover canopy area</li>
  <li>5,550m² high truss warehouse space</li>
  <li>1,600m² maintenance facility</li>
  <li>45,000 Litre self bunded diesel fuelling station</li>
  <li>700m² Spare parts area for fleet &amp; rental spares</li>
  <li>460m² segregated undercover</li>
  <li>90m² truck wash bay facility with oil separation system</li>
  <li>Onsite lifting to 16tonne</li>
</ul>
```

`$("#perth-features").click(func....` when the element with id of perth-features is clicked ...

`$("ul#perth-list li").each(function(index)` for each of the items in your list - using the index as a paramater...

`$(this).delay(400 * index).fadeIn(300);` Fade in each item in the list with incremental fade delay.

Comment: Perfect! Simple and works great. Thanks! Two small alterations – can I make them slide down rather than fade? I also need to be able to close it again.

EDIT: Figured out the slide down (change fadeIn to slideDown) but this is just a reveal sort of effect. I want the list items themselves to physically slide down from the title.

Comment: @ColinStewart I've updated my post - hopefully this helps... Please elaborate on what you mean with the slideDown... Going off line for a couple hours now, so goodluck in the meantime.

Comment: Works perfectly! Don't worry about the slide down. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer to stick to just HTML:

For a drop down list in HTML you could use a `<select>` tag. This is normally used when the user is asked to choose an option from a list. But, I guess you could still use this method for just display purposes in your case.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Your first line of text would go into the first option tag.

Instead of `<li>` tags use `<option>`

```
<select>
     <li>15,000m² heavy duty concrete hardstand open storage</li>
    <li>1,900m² heavy duty concrete undercover canopy area</li>
    <li>5,550m² high truss warehouse space</li>
    <li>1,600m² maintenance facility</li>
    <li>45,000 Litre self bunded diesel fuelling station</li>
    <li>700m² Spare parts area for fleet &amp; rental spares</li>
    <li>460m² segregated undercover</li>
    <li>90m² truck wash bay facility with oil separation system</li>
    <li>Onsite lifting to 16tonne</li>
</select>
```